# dapper GetList(predicate) vs Query(sql condition)

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions

In **dapper** I can get data with

```
Query<Person>("sql condition").
```

and I can do with **dapper extensions**

```
GetList<Person>(predicate)
```

Both return an IEnumerable

Which approach should I choose for which situation?

As the extensions library is newer it seems to me that the author did not like building sql

conditions with strings. Instead I have a bit of intellisense and strong typing the

condition.

But is that all the advantage? Are there disadvantages you are aware of due to experience

in using both libraries?

Comment: GetList here - is that "rainbow"? Or your own custom method? (Dapper core doesn't have a GetList)

Comment: its dapper extensions and I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

The DapperExtension is there to help with the simple task of CRUD against a single table. If you need more then Query is the way to handle this. Admittedly SELECT is not as useful as it is a single table, but it has simplified many of the write operations.